# i want to upload images through send_keys() but it gives different output?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i want to upload multiple images on web page with send_keys() method. 
i tried this code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(link)
file_list = []
file_list.append('D:\\01.jpg')
file_list.append('D:\\02.jpg')
file_list.append('D:\\03.jpg')

for img in file_list:
    upload = browser.find_element_by_name('upload')
    upload.send_keys(img)
```

this code run without error, but it upload 6 images.

i want output like uploaded images is 01.jpg , 02.jpg ,03.jpg

but it gives output uploaded images is 01.jpg , 01.jpg ,02.jpg , 01.jpg , 02.jpg , 03.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining your `find_element` and `send_keys` statements here. Nothing in your code indicates why the images would be uploading twice though, so it might be an underlying issue on the web page itself and the way it has been programmed to accept file input.

```
from time import sleep


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(link)
file_list = []
file_list.append('D:\\01.jpg')
file_list.append('D:\\02.jpg')
file_list.append('D:\\03.jpg')

for img in file_list:
    print(img)
    browser.find_element_by_name('upload').send_keys(img)
    sleep(5)
```

If `img` only prints 3 times, but 6 images are uploaded, then it's an issue with the web page and not a Selenium issue. I added a 5 second explicit sleep to give the web page some time to process your file uploads, which may be part of the issue here.

You can change the `sleep(5)` to some kind of `WebDriverWait` using `ExpectedConditions` to wait for an element on the page indicating the upload is successful -- if you'd like some help with this, seeing the HTML on the page you are trying to automate would be a good place to start.

Hope this helps a bit.